# Disable developerprofile file from Xcode 5

Tags: xcode5

How to disable the developerprofile file exported from Xcode 5? I exported the file to a team member who is no longer a valid member. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to just create a new development certificate and revoke the old one.